# I'm confused about return methods in java

Tags: java, return

I have a method that is looking for vowels:

```
 public boolean isVowel(char ch) {
    String vowels = "aeiou";
    char[] chars = vowels.toCharArray();
    for (char letter : chars) {
        if (letter == Character.toUpperCase(ch) || letter == Character.toLowerCase(ch)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Why doesn't this statement ALWAYS return false? The last line is outside of both the 'for' loop and the conditional statement. Shouldn't it override the true returned within the inner statement?

Comment: You are confused about return statements. The first (and only) return statement that gets executed determines the value returned by the method.

Comment: All the possible condition to return true is checked in the loop so it is good to return false if neither of that condition got satisfied.

Comment: BTW, you can shorten your first two lines into a simple `char[] chars = { 'a','e','i','o','u' };` instead of creating a string that you won't use beyond that.

Comment: This could be a one-liner like `return "aeiou".indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(ch)) != -1`

Comment: But what about poor left-out "sometimes `y`"? ;-)

Comment: Thank you....Not sure how I've made it this far not realizing that only the first return gets executed!  I've been struggling with this for a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` doesn't just set what the method's return value will be when it ends, it also ends the execution of the method, right then and there. In your case, that means when it hits `return true;`, it exits the loop (doesn't finish it) and the method right away, returning `true`.

It's only if the loop's `if` never branches into that `return true;` that you reach the end of the method, which returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, when you return in a  method, the code exits and doesn't execute anything later in that method.

Once the code returns in the for loop, no other later code in that method (like the `return false`) will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `return` the method execution ends there and returns the value. `return true;` will return `true`, no netter what other `return` statements return.

`return false;` will be executed only if the `if` condition is not met even once.